# Holdout Layer not using AlphaMaps in Blender 2.8

Tags: transparency, render-layers

It seems that the HoldOut Option in Blender 2.8 does not use alphaMaps with transparency to create a proper holdout ? can somebody confirm this or do I have to tick some option to get this to work ?

or any Workaround ?

thx

[image]

[image][image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create two View Layers.
In the first one, check only *Indirect Only* for your Small_Bushes collection. Nothing else.

In the second view layer, disable your others collections with the checkbox to the left of the collection.

Add an alpha over node to mix the 2 layer.